# Custom Environments in ASP .Net Core Secret Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

We have deviated away from the Microsoft standard environment setup abit at our firm.

We have the following Environemnts

- Local - Environment for local deving against a docker compose file with the infrastructure running as containers
- Development - An integration environment for 3rd Party Teams where we hook our apis into the frontend they are working on. Quite unstable as integration enivornments should be
- Staging - An environment more stable for our stake holders to review

Our `Startup.cs` class looks something like this

```
    public void ConfigureLocalServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
            .AddApplicationServices(Configuration)
            .AddLocalIntegrationEvents(Configuration)
            .AddLocalLogging(Configuration);
    }

    public void ConfigureDevelopmentServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
            .AddApplicationServices(Configuration)
            .AddDevelopmentLogging(Configuration)
            .AddDevelopmentIntegrationEvents(Configuration);
    }
```

As you can see its nice and neat and we configure our application per environment.

Now on to our issue - due to the default web builder only adding in user secrets if the environment is Development ( which as I understand is default environment you should use if you are working locally) we are having issues with run time exceptions with the kestrel HTTPS certificate not being loaded as this secret is 
 now missing `"Kestrel:Certificates:Development:Password": "100e0e22-09ea-40e4-bef9-469289bf8786"`.

I have temporaliy resolved the issue by doing this

```
        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
            {
                //Load in secrets if environment is local as well to get our HTTPS certs loaded correctly
                if (hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName.Equals("Local", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                    config.AddUserSecrets<Startup>();

            })
             .UseStartup<Startup>()
             .UseSerilog();
```

Some devs have secrets set though that are specific for ANOTHER environment and this causes more issues at runtime.

As far as I understand Secret files are not environment specific so we cant add in "Local Secrets".

What is the best way to resolve this issue for us ? Is our approach completely incorrect?

Answer (score 5):

The user secrets are only for local development. This is why they default to only be active when the environment is set to `Development`.

This is also the reason why you need to use your workaround:

```cs
.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
            {
                //Load in secrets if environment is local as well to get our HTTPS certs loaded correctly
                if (hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName.Equals("Local", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                    config.AddUserSecrets<Startup>();

            })
```

### Workaround: Per environment user secrets

A workaround would be to have multiple secret file GUIDs and use this overload with different GUIDs based on your environment:

```
var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName;
if(env == 'Local')
  config.AddUserSecrets(new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000").ToString());
if(env == 'Development')
  config.AddUserSecrets(new Guid("11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111").ToString());
```

> **Note:** If you do this the context menu in visual studio might not show the correct file when you click on `Manage User Secrets`.
>
> Instead find this directory:
>
> ```
> C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets
> ```
>
> In that directory you create a directory (if it doesn't already exist) with the same GUID you used above.
>   Then add a `secrets.json` file, like so:
>
> [image: user secrets directory and file]

### Alternative 1: Different configuration provider

But since it sounds like you also want to share secrets between developers. You could use a different configuration provider.

For example the `Azure Key Vault provider` as outlined here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1

This allows to manage all the secrets in the cloud without sending them through instant message etc.

### Alternative 2: Custom configuration provider

If you don't like azure, there are providers which do the same for other services, or if none of them works for you, you can create a custom one that fits your needs.

Here is a blog post documenting how to do that:
https://codeburst.io/create-a-custom-configuration-provider-in-asp-net-core-cdd6a32b8ecb